# Dual of the barrier transformed linear program $\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \left\{ c^T x - \mu \sum_{j=1}^n \log(x_j) : Ax = b; x \geq 0 \right\}$

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Dual of the following linear program
\begin{align}
\text{minimize}_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \quad & c^T x \ -\mu \sum_{j=1}^n \log(x_j) \\
\text{subject to }\quad &  Ax = b\\
& x \geq 0 \ ,
\end{align}
where $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, and $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$.

---

*Partial attempt*

Defining, $X = {\rm diag}(x)$ and $1$ as a column vector of all ones.

Forming the Lagrangian such that 
\begin{align}
L(x,y,z) &= c^T x - \mu 1^T \log(x) + y^T\left( Ax - b\right) - z^T(x) \ .
\end{align}

The dual can be obtained as
\begin{align}
g(y,z) := \inf_x L(x,y,z) 
\end{align}

So, 
\begin{align}
0 \in \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} \Longrightarrow c - \mu X^{-1} 1 + A^T y - z = 0 \ .
\end{align}

Now, how to proceed and derive the dual. or is there some other way to derive the dual? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You seem to have dropped the $z$ in your stationarity conditions

Comment: oops ... thanks .. now fixed it. please suggest

Comment: You seem to be mixing two similar concepts - kkt conditions and duality. A dual problem is obtained by minimizing a Lagrangian over $x$. Complementarity and primal feasibility are not related to the construction of the dual in any way.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.